# Hybrid Satellite Base with Openlayers does not work

Tags: openlayers, mapbox, bing-maps, aerial-photography

Using OpenStreetMap base with OpenLayers but would also like a satellite base.
Thought of Bing, MapBox, however, are not working. What is wrong?

This is the code for the Bing satellite base, which doesn't work:

```
var layer_bing_aerial = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: ' Bing',
    visible: false,
    type: 'base',
    preload: Infinity,
    source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
        // We need a key to get the layer from the provider. 
        // Sign in with Bing Maps and you will get your key (for free)
        key: '<My Bing Maps Key>',
        imagerySet: 'AerialWithLabelsOnDemand', 
        // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the Bing Maps
        // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
        maxZoom: 19
    })
});
```

Code with MapBox that doesn't work

```
var layer_satelite2 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: ' MapBox',
    visible: false,
    type: 'base',
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<My Mapbox Token>'
    })
});

var layer_satelite3 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: ' MapBox',
    visible: false,
    type: 'base',
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9.html?title=true&access_token=<My Mapbox Token>#3/0/0'
    })
});
```

This code worked, however, I would like to show besides the satellite, the name of the streets (hybrid). Any suggestion?

```
var layer_satelite = new ol.layer.Tile({
    title: ' Esri World Imagery',
    visible: false,
    type: 'base',
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: ['Powered by Esri',
               'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'],
        attributionsCollapsible: false,
        url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        maxZoom: 29
    })
});
```

Comment: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html `AerialWithLabelsOnDemand`

Comment: @Mike, I'm using another version, and even accessing the link `https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/examples/bing-maps.html` doesn't work

Comment: That is because it is using old out of date API key. Just replace `AerialWithLabels` with `AerialWithLabelsOnDemand` and in your own code and it should work.

Comment: Replace `AerialWithLabels` with `AerialWithLabelsOnDemand` (edited code), however it still doesn't show the base.